# Solr query with a list?

Tags: java, solr

How can a list be entered into a solr query?

I'm trying to perform a solr query which matches a list.

For example, I have a data structure similar to the one below where `someList` is a list which may contain any number of string items.

```
{
 someKey:someValue,
 someList: [
  "item1",
  "item2"
 ]
}
```

I want to return all records with specific values in `someList`. So if my query is `q=someKey:* AND someList:items`, I should receive only those records whose list `someList` matches the list, `items`, in my query.

I attempted something similar to the below method, but the query behaves as if "*" is being passed to `someList` in the query annotation. That, the query is being generated incorrectly as `q=someKey:someValue AND someList:*` rather than as `q=someKey:someValue AND someList:items`.

```
@Query("someKey:?0* AND someList:?1*")
public Page<Results> queryMethod(
        String someValue,
        List<String> items,
        Pageable pageable);
```

This method is in an interface which extends the SolrCrudRepository.

How can a list be entered into a solr query?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the `List<String> items` just pass Space seperated values as:

```
someList:(item1 item2)
```

Change your method :

```
@Query("someKey:?0* AND someList:?1*")
public Page<Results> queryMethod(
        String someValue,
        String items, <<<----
        Pageable pageable);
```

For detailed info for querying in SOLR you can refer [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrQuerySyntax)

Comment: But the list query size is indeterminate. It could be any number of items.